# Regular expressions in converting wide to long dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 102, 103),
  dmpfc_selfrefneg = c(1,2,3),
  dmpfc_selfimmneg = c(1,2,3),
  dmpfc_socrefneg = c(1,2,3),
  dmpfc_socimmneg = c(1,2,3),
  tpj_selfrefneg = c(1,2,3),
  tpj_selfimmneg = c(1,2,3),
  tpj_socrefneg = c(1,2,3),
  tpj_socimmneg = c(1,2,3)
)
```

The ideal output is:

```
d_ideal <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103),
  roi = c('dmpfc', 'dmpfc', 'dmpfc', 'dmpfc', 'tpj', 'tpj', 'tpj', 'tpj'),
  condition = c('selfrefneg', 'selfimmneg', 'socrefneg', 'socimmneg', 'selfrefneg', 'selfimmneg', 'socrefneg', 'socimmneg'),
  value = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
)
```

The values for `roi` and `condition` are basically the column names in `d` separated by an underscore.

I know I can use `pivot_longer` or `gather` to convert dataframe from wide to long, but how can I do it smartly with the column names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(d, cols = -sub, names_to = c("roi", "condition"), names_sep = "_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 4
     sub roi   condition  value
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1   101 dmpfc selfrefneg     1
 2   101 dmpfc selfimmneg     1
 3   101 dmpfc socrefneg      1
 4   101 dmpfc socimmneg      1
 5   101 tpj   selfrefneg     1
 6   101 tpj   selfimmneg     1
 7   101 tpj   socrefneg      1
 8   101 tpj   socimmneg      1
 9   102 dmpfc selfrefneg     2
10   102 dmpfc selfimmneg     2
# … with 14 more rows
```

---

Or do

```
d %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -sub) %>% 
   separate_wider_delim(name, delim = "_", names = c("roi", "condition"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 4
     sub roi   condition  value
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1   101 dmpfc selfrefneg     1
 2   101 dmpfc selfimmneg     1
 3   101 dmpfc socrefneg      1
 4   101 dmpfc socimmneg      1
 5   101 tpj   selfrefneg     1
 6   101 tpj   selfimmneg     1
 7   101 tpj   socrefneg      1
 8   101 tpj   socimmneg      1
 9   102 dmpfc selfrefneg     2
10   102 dmpfc selfimmneg     2
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Why do you need to rename? why not just use `names_to = c('roi', 'condition')`?